# Segfault when reading stream

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to get the output from a command which is being run in the background as follows:

```
    def OnRun(self, event):
        """Run the command entered in the command widget."""

        # Allow redirection of command I/O so we can capture it
        process = wx.Process(self)
        process.Redirect()

        # Run the command
        pid = wx.Execute(self.commandCtrl.GetValue(), wx.EXEC_ASYNC, process)

        # Copy the output from the command to the results widget
        stream = process.GetInputStream()
        while stream.CanRead():
            line = stream.readline().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            self.resultsCtrl.AppendText(line)
            wx.Yield()
```

When I run this code with a short-lived executable (eg `ls`) I get a segfault at the `readline()`. For a long-running command I don't get the segfault, but I also don't see any results in the display (both `commandCtrl` and `resultsCtrl` are `wx.TextCtrl` widgets).

I guess the segfault is because the stream is removed after the command finished executing, so how do I ensure I read the results before the stream is deleted?

For update, I was expecting the `wx.Yield()` call to allow the update to be seen, so either no text is being received (by the `readline()` or the display is not being updated. Any ideas why that is?